# SQL injection finders

Tags: java, sql, security, static-analysis

We have a Java based client/server project. Recently one of the testers has found a SQL injection vulnerability while testing the application.

We do not have enough resources to manually check the application for SQL injections.

Are there any SQL injection finders / static code analyzers that find SQL vulnerabilities in Java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes!

Here are some:

- [Armorize CodeSecure](http://www.armorize.com/codesecure/index.php)
- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [YASCA](http://www.scovetta.com/yasca.html)
- [HP Fortify Static Code Analyzer](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/products/hp-fortify-software-security-center/hp-fortify-static-code-analyzer/)
- [Parasoft](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/capabilities/static_analysis_java.jsp)
- [klockwork INSIGHT](http://www.klocwork.com/products/insight/)
- [coverity Static Analysis](http://www.coverity.com/products/static-analysis.html)
- [VeraCode](http://www.veracode.com/products/static)
- [Checkmarx](http://www.checkmarx.com/technology/static-code-analysis-sca/)
- [IBM Appscan](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/appscan/)

Read: [OWASP's List of Source Analysis Tools](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools)

Answer (score 0):

Findbugs does have a module to check for them, but did not run it myself yet.
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/FindSqlInjection.html